# bind unordered list recursively in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a datatble as below:

```
id         menuname                      url                         parentid
1        Home                        ~/Home.aspx                    NULL    
2        Product                        ~/products.aspx                NULL 
3        Services                    ~/services.aspx                NULL    
4        ERP                            ~/erp.aspx                    2
5        HRM                            ~/hrm.aspx                    4
7        Payroll                        ~/payroll.aspx                4
8        Programming                    ~/programming.aspx            3
9        Advertising                    ~/advert.aspx                3
10        Television Advert            ~/tvadvert.aspx                9
11        Radio Advert                ~/radioadvert.aspx            9
```

So i want to generate menu item into an unordered list based on the datatable above such that the items with null `parentid` should be the first level menu
and others will be submenus based on their `parentid` like so:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="home.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="produc.aspx">Product</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a href="erp.aspx">ERP</a>    
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="hrm.aspx">HRM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="payroll.aspx">Payroll</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="services.aspx">Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="programming.aspx">Advertising</a></li>
                <li><a href="advert.aspx">Programming</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>

    .....etc
</ul>
```

Problem is that i cant understand how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var dtrow = dt.Select("parentid is null or parentid=''");
    var str = new StringBuilder();
    str.Append("<ul class='menu'>");
    if (dtrow.Any())
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dtrow)
        {
            str.AppendFormat("<li><a href='{0}'>{1}</a></li>", row["url"].ToString(), row["menuname"].ToString());
            var crow = dt.Select("parentid='" + row["id"] + "'");
            if (crow.Any())
            {
                 str.Append("<ul>");
                 foreach (DataRow drow in crow)
                 {
                     var ccrow = dt.Select("parentid='" + drow["id"] + "'");
                     if (ccrow.Any())
                     {
                         str.AppendFormat("<li><a href='{0}'>{1}</a>", drow["url"], drow["menuname"]);
                         str.Append("<ul>");
                         foreach (DataRow dcrow in ccrow)
                         {
                             str.AppendFormat("<li><a href='{0}'>{1}</a></li>", dcrow["url"], dcrow["menuname"]);
                         }
                         str.Append("</ul>");
                         str.Append("</li>");

                     }
                     else
                     {
                         str.AppendFormat("<li><a href='{0}'>{1}</a></li>", drow["url"], drow["menuname"]);
                     }

                 }
                 str.Append("</ul>");

            }

        }

    }
    else
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            str.AppendFormat("<li><a href='{0}'>{1}</a></li>", row["url"], row["menuname"]);
        }
    }
    str.Append("</ul>");
```